# Why is my custom hook for data fetching called multiple times?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, rendering

I'm building a simple website that fetches content from a CMS when the page loads. When I use the React useState and useEffect hook inside the component and log the state variable `content`, it behaves as expected. However, if create a custom hook out of it, the data is fetched twice.

When I use the hooks inside the component it works fine:

```js
const AboutUsPage = () => {
   const [content, setContent] = useState(null);
   const [error, setError] = useState(null);
   const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  
   useEffect(() => {
      const fetchData = async () => {
         try {
            const result = await client.getEntries({
               content_type: 'aboutUsPage',
                include: 10,
            });

            setData(result.items[0].fields);

         } catch (e) {
            setError(e);
         } finally {
            setLoading(false);
         }
    };

    fetchData();

  }, []);

  console.log(content);

  return (
     <>
        {content && <p>We have content!</p>}
     </>

  );

};
```

**Output**

```js
null
{title: "About us Page", header: {…}}
```

This I expect, because `fetchData()` is called after the component is mounted for the first time, and then rendered again with data. However, if I create a custom hook, for some reason the data is fetched twice. I tried this with `contentType` as a dependency and `[]` as a dependency, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. I also already disabled React.StrictMode.

**useData.js**

```js
const useData = (contentType) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const result = await client.getEntries({
          content_type: contentType,
          include: 10,
        });

        setData(result.items[0].fields);

      } catch (e) {
        setError(e);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };

    fetchData();

  }, [contentType]);

  return [loading, error, data];
};
```

**AboutUsPage.js**

```js
const AboutUsPage = () => {
  const [error, loading, content] = useData('aboutUsPage');

  console.log(content);

  return (
     <>
        {content && <p>We have content!</p>}
     </>

  );
}
```

**Output**

```js
null
{title: "About us Page", header: {…}}
{title: "About us Page", header: {…}}
```

I don't really understand why or what I can do to fix this.

Comment: One way you can find out is by Installing React DevTools and using the Profiler to find out why a compinent re-rendered.

Comment: I suspect this could be related to `useState`'s batching. State updates are batched in certain contexts, and not batched in others. It could be that since batching is an implementation detail, the `setData` and `setLoading` updates get batched in the first example, but not in the latter. If you remove the `setLoading` call in the latter, do you still see the same double render?

Comment: And is the data really fetched twice (look at your browser's devtools' Network tab)  or does it just render twice?

Comment: I just checked and the data isn't fetched twice, so it's just the render. Removing the setLoading call does fix it... But I don't really understand why? Is there something I can read about this to help me understand it?

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong ordering returning [loading, error, data] and getting back [error, loading, content].

The first thing that happen to you not make any sense because in finally you also setLoading(false);

React state updates via useState hooks are not grouped together into a single rerender in some cases. you can read about it [here](https://medium.com/swlh/react-state-batch-update-b1b61bd28cd2)

I have created for you a codeSandbox example to illustrate that those 2 scenarios not related to custom hook but to twice calls to setState [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-microservice-12uh2?file=/src/index.js)